# PHPUnit, Selenium - Click on link in row based on the value of another column in the same row

Tags: selenium, phpunit

I think it's a stupid question, but I cant find an answer. I have table with many columns (name, date, link, etc.). I want to click on link based on the "name" value.

Here is short example:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    name value
  </td>
  <td>
    date
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="">
      link
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  the same format with different values
</tr>
```

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This xpath will work for you, I think:

```
//td[contains(text(), 'name value')]/../td/a
```

It will find the `<td>` that contains `'name value'`, go back up to the containing `<tr>`, then back down to the `<td>` that has a`<a>` as a child in the same `<tr>`.

If I understand phpunit correctly, the command will look something like this:

```
$this->click("xpath=//td[contains(text(), 'name value')]/../td/a");
```